# Comment with /*! in SCSS causes many empty lines in CSS

Tags: css, sass, comments

In one of the SCSS files of a bigger Rails project the is a comment that looks like

```
/*!
Text text text text

Text text text
*/
```

This file is `@import`ed into another SCSS file which is itself `@import`ed into a SCSS file which is the one which will be compiled to CSS.

In the compiled CSS file there are many many empty lines directly before this comment. When I remove the `!` it works as expected and there are no empty lines.

I know that a comment which starts with `/*!` should be immune to compression tools. But I think the described behaviour is not intended. Does anyone have a clue what happens here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/e235d7654a9c9f447575.  Compiling it locally using imports has the same results.

Comment: What kind of output style do you use?

Comment: @Rito The output style is :compressed.